# Django DRF image field does not accept null values

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Django DRF image field does not accept null values.

My model consists of `image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True, null=True)`

If I upload a file there's no problem. But, if I leave it blank it gives  the following error:

`The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.`

I want to make the image field optional So I set `null=True` and `blank=True`. But this does not seem to work.

Comment: Can you add the full traceback and the code to your relevant models.py and views.py, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In DRF your model passes through serializer add this to your serializer:

```
class ImagePostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = models.ImagePost
```

Comment: I tried this, it is still giving me the same error

Comment: u need also to pass an empty string in formData request

Answer (score 1):

Use the DRF Imagefield in serializer

```
serializers.ImageField(required=False)
```

DRF ImageField is validating  the uploaded file content as matching a known image format. Corresponds to `django.forms.fields.ImageField`

```
ImageField(max_length=None, allow_empty_file=False, use_url=UPLOADED_FILES_USE_URL)
```

Refer: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#imagefield

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I was using a different serializer to create an instance of that model. I removed the serializer and now it is working.